# Everything in UI is widened after installing Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, display-resolution, 20.10

I have a wider than usual aspect ratio on every UI component after I've just installed a clean Ubuntu 20.10 on a HP machine (Intel® Core™ i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4) with Intel® HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1). How can I installed drivers so that aspect ratio is normal. All my trials on installed third pat drivers have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your monitor resolution
And set it to real value of your monitor

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-resolution.html.en

If you still have trouble with gpu drivers then try pop os or manjaro. They have better gpu detection and automatic Installation of gpu drivers

Comment: I've tried to change the resolution, but the aspect ratio still remain the same.

Comment: Which resolutions are available on your pc ?

Comment: Available resolution are 1024 x 768 (4:3) the default one, and 800 x 600 (4:3). My monitor size is 21 inches.

Comment: 1024 x 768 (4:3) the default one,  and 800 x 600 (4:3). The monitor size is 21 inches.

Comment: 1024 x 768 (4:3) the default one,  and 800 x 600 (4:3). The monitor size is 21 inches.

Comment: That appears to be graphics driver issue. Try reinstalling Ubuntu if everything else failed.